# Can´t get absoluteX and absoluteY from image using itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I try to get a image (jpg format) from url to put in my pdf using itext 5.0.5 with this simple code below:

```
Image imageToShow = null; 
imageToShow = Image.getInstance(new URL("any image url here"));
imageToShow.scaleAbsolute(size[0], size[1]);
```

I get the image but the value from absoluteX and absoluteY is always a 'NaN' value and this problem prevents me to change this values (third line), what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: iText 5.0.5 is ancient. Have you tried with a current version?

Comment: yes, I tried the 5.5.10, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a situation where you can switch to another iText version, try out iText7.

The equivalent code would be:

```
// src url
String somePath = "https://www.pdfa.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/ITSC-Logo-Horizontal-RGB-300dpi.png";

// fetch image data
ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(new URL(somePath));

// turn into image object
Image image  = new Image(imageData);

// perform scaling operation
image = image.scaleAbsolute(120f, 120f);

// debug    
System.out.println(image.getImageWidth() + "x" + image.getImageHeight());
```

Comment: I can't, unfortunately.